# Как сделать плавный переход картинок при клике на стрелки

Tags: javascript, css

Не получается сделать плавный переход картинок на чистом css и javascript как сделать помогите ребят. Везде используют JQuery но он не нужен.
Есть слайдер и стрелки влево и вправо при клике на них нужен плавный переход картинок

```
 <div id="slider" onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').pause()">
        <label for="notebook2a_1" style="margin-top:6px;">Gallery</label>
                <div class="left_arrow">
                    <img src="full/left_arrow.png" id="left_arrow"/>
                </div>
                <div class="right_arrow">
                    <img src="full/right_arrow.png" id="right_arrow"/>
                </div>
                <img src="full/1.png" id="mainImage" class="mainImage"/>
        <ul class="thumbs">
            <li class="img1"><img src="Thumbs/1.png" class="mini active" data-full-url="full/1.png"
                                  onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/1_over.png'"
                                  onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/1.png'"/></li>
            <li class="img2"><img src="Thumbs/2.png" class="mini"  data-full-url="full/2.png"
                                  onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/2_over.png'"
                                  onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/2.png'"/></li>
            <li class="img3"><img src="Thumbs/3.png" class="mini"  data-full-url="full/3.png"
                                  onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/3_over.png'"
                                  onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/3.png'"/></li>
            <li class="img4"><img src="Thumbs/4.png" class="mini" data-full-url="full/4.png"
                                  onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/4_over.png'"
                                  onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/4.png'"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: такое подойдет? - https://github.com/nueq22/air-slider
вот демо - http://www.cssscript.com/demo/automatic-responsive-image-slider-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: @nueq да ))))))

Comment: @nueq но как его применить к моему не получается

Comment: скачали архив, подключили css, js, поменяли разметку на div'ы (у вас список) и инициировали слайдер с указанием параметров внизу страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте transition для для слайдера

```js
var images = [
  'https://hdwallpaperz.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/hd-wallpaper-nature-1080p-14.jpg',
  'https://hdwallpaperz.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Latest-full-HD-Wallpapers-Tower.jpg',
  'https://i.imgpile.com/4cd3e700aee52ea5532170b67c3c4d48.jpg'
]
var images_length = images.length;
images_length--;
function prev() {
  images_length--;
  if (images_length < 0){
      images_length = images.length -1;
  }
      document.getElementById('slider').style.backgroundImage = "url("+images[images_length]+")";
}
function next() {
  images_length++;
    if (images_length > images.length -1){
      images_length = 0;
  }
      document.getElementById('slider').style.backgroundImage = "url("+images[images_length]+")";
}
setInterval(next, 5000)
```

```css
#slider {
  background-image:url(https://hdwallpaperz.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/hd-wallpaper-nature-1080p-14.jpg);
  width:400px;
  height:250px;
  background-size:cover;  transition:1s all;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="prev()">&lt;</button>
<button onclick="next()">&gt;</button>
<div id="slider"></div>
```